# Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.javac.Main

Tags: java, jvm

Today I installed java in c:\Java in my system, after this set the path of the java in windows environment variable. I have windows 8. When I try to run the command `javac` in command prompt i will generate error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.javac.Main
```

Comment: You're either missing part of the JDK (tools.jar) or your classpath is not set up correctly.

Comment: how to set classpath manually ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: Are you OCP-JP and don't know how to search for this problem on the net?

Comment: Find the same [question](http://www.coderanch.com/t/562210/java/java/Error-find-load-main-class)

Comment: i know the how to search the problem , for that reason i use stackoverflow , when good answer not found  @Luiggi Mendoza . and know my problem is solve.